# Center children widget in parent widget(parent widget was added in layout)

Tags: c++, qt

I created a **layout contain a parent widget**. In that parent widget i created another widget.

My code is similarly to this:

```
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout();
QWidget *parentWidget = new QWidget();
layout->addWidget(parentWidget );
QWidget *childWidget = new QWidget(parentWidget);
```

[image]

**How can i center the child widget in parent widget ?**

The problem is we cannot get the true size of parent widget because it's in a layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the child inside the parent's `showeEvent`. You can use a `bool` flag to do it only when the parent is shown for the first time.

```
void Parent::showEvent(QShowEvent *)
{
    if(_first_show)
    {
        _first_show = false;
        _child->move(this->rect().center() - _child->rect().center());
    }
}
```

Proof that it works (red is the parent, and blue is the child):

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for being patient with me. Can i ask you another thing? If i follow this method, i will have to create a class for parent widget right ?

Comment: @user2652023 It would be ideal, but you won't have to. You could use [event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters), but it would just lead to ugly code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting fixed size of child widget and placing it inside grid layout of parent widget.

```
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout();
QWidget *parentWidget = new QWidget();
layout->addWidget(parentWidget );
QWidget *childWidget = new QWidget(parentWidget);
QGridLayout *parentLayout = new QGridLayout();
parentWidget->setLayout(parentLayout);
parentLayout->addWidget(childWidget);
childWidget->setFixedSize(/*some fixed size for child widget*/);
```

Comment: how can i move the child widget to center with setFixedSize() ? Thanks

Comment: @user2652023, Grid layout places widget in the center of its cell, but if you don't set fixed size, child widget is going to be the same size as parent (minus margins)

Comment: That is my purpose, i want parent widget bigger than child widget, my code above is just use to illustrate my idea. The image is the real interface i want

Comment: @user2652023, for this you can simply use snippet I wrote

Comment: Now i understood your idea, thanks. However, for some purposes my code need to follow my flow above because i want child widget to move freely inside parent. Can you give me another suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @user2652023, I think Andrei R's answer is valid to your question as it is. You didn't mention that you want to move child widget inside the parent. Maybe you could accept his answer and post new question: "How to move child widget inside the parent (by user input or programatically?)".

Comment: @Tomas: I have already programed to move child widget freely. I just want to know how can i move child widget to center when first open it.

Comment: @user2652023 Catch the `showEvent` of your `Parent widget` and move the child to the center. You can use a `bool` flag to ensure you only do this once, when the widget is shown for the first time.

Comment: @thuga how can i calculate the position of the center ? Thanks

Comment: @user2652023 Get the widget's [rectangle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#rect-prop) and get the [center](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#center) from it. `somewidget->rect().center()`. Something like `child->move(parent->rect().center() - child->rect().center());` should work.

Comment: @thuga parent is inside a layout so it rect() will not return the true size so its center may be incorect, thanks you anyway.

Comment: @user2652023 Works flawlessly if you do it inside the parent's `showEvent`. See my answer.

Comment: @user2652023 You should also edit your question and put all the extra info in it, that you left as comments on this answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108872/discussion-between-user2652023-and-thuga).

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the layout of the `parentWidget`, you can simply place the `childWidget` inside of a `QGridLayout` that has spacers on either side.

```cpp
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout();
QWidget *parentWidget = new QWidget();
layout->addWidget(parentWidget);

QGridLayout *parentLayout = new QGridLayout(&parentWidget);
parentLayout->addItem(new QSpacerItem(0,0, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding),0,0);
parentLayout->addItem(new QSpacerItem(0,0, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding),2,2);
QWidget *childWidget = new QWidget();
parentLayout->addWidget(&childWidget, 1, 1);
```